# Provide cross-network tag search

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, stackexchange.com

The number of sites in the Stack Exchange network is ever growing, and often the topics overlap to some degree. So for topics on the borderline between communities, a user might well have difficulties to choose the best site where to post his question.

**I propose a search for tags on the main [stackexchange.com](https://stackexchange.com/) site.** At the very least, the result should list tags containing the search term along with the network sites on which they are used.

Additional information would be welcome, particularly some activity measure like accept rate or number of questions, to see which community is most active on a given tag. The short descriptions of the tags for the respective sites would probably be useful as well.

## Example

Let us suppose I search the global site for `svg`. At the time of this writing, the result should list the following sites and numbers of questions:

- 3,612 on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/svg)
- 58 on [Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/svg)
- 30 on [TeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg)
- 26 on [Graphic Design](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg)
- 18 on [GIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg)
- 11 on [ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/svg)
- 10 on [Game Development](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg)
- 5 on [Pro Webmasters](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg)
- 4 on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg)
- 2 on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg)
- 2 on [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg)
- 1 on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg)

Some of these might come rather unexpected, although in retrospect they do make a lot of sense. Some of these sites I wasn't even aware of so far. Now I can consider which of the audiences that deals in SVG is most likely to answer my particular question.

Note that the above list was created manually, and thus might be incomplete. Also note that the list only considers exact matches, not substring matches. Having both would be best, but having either would be sufficient for the purpose of this request.

Answer (score 4):

In a small way, this feature is already available: when you [construct a tag set](https://stackexchange.com/filters/new) on SE, then after you enter a tag, you see a list of sites which provide that tag, along with question counts.

- This does only search full tags, not parts of a tag name. Which might be a valid restriction, as this should still cover the most common use case of a full tag name.
- The number of matching questions is already included, which is a great thing. They differ slightly from the numbes above, perhaps due to closed questions.
- This does not provide a link to the site, so users can't easily see examples of what kinds of questions a site covers.
- The [single hit](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/66354/is-there-a-free-command-line-program-for-converting-pdf-files-to-svg) on [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/svg) was omitted, which is OK I think.
- The whole thing is hidden somewhere in the depths of the question filter UI, which is not an obvious place to obtain this information, and which is pretty much a power-user tool.

I guess it shouldn't be too hard to adjust that existing code to provide a stand-alone tag search as requested.

Answer (score 3):

My only concern is that the tags may not be defined the same way across sites, making cross-search difficult.

Comment: That's why I'd include the short description. In the end, the user has to decide, but he will be happy to use all the help he can get. Even a listing with a few false positives is better than no listing at all.